# How can I send an array of JSON objects as a GET parameter?

Tags: php, json, netaxept

I'm using Netaxept as an epayment system for a client and I'm having trouble with the before mentioned question.

I'm trying to choose which cards to display at the payment terminal. At the API it says that

"The paymentMethodActionList is an array of JSON objects, each representing a rule to how to handle cards, e.g:

```
     [{"PaymentMethod":"Visa","Fee":"100"},{"PaymentMethod":null,"Fee":"200"}]"
```

So what I want to do something like this

```
$url = 'test.payment.nets.com/?paymentMethodActionList=[{"PaymentMethod":"Visa","Fee":"100"},{"PaymentMethod":null,"Fee":"200"}]';
```

but the Netsaxept gives me an internal error.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should not use `Get` with a Json array. Use `post` instead

Comment: @Guns — Why not? Is there something in the Netaxept documentation that specifies that?

Comment: You will likely run into trouble if there's too much json content in the url (there are limits for GET params) and it might get trimmed ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode the value. Also be aware that you may hit the size limit for such GET request.

Comment: I url encoded the value, but I'm getting

<Message>Malformed PaymentMethodActionList</Message>

error

Comment: POST is really the solution. Its a waste of time to url encode etc when all thats needed is a  POST with a document body...